# Why does my AWS dashboard shows 2 buckets while I have just 1 application? Is it due to CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, bucket

I am quite a noob in AWS services. Since last year, I have been successfully keeping a personal blog (static website) using S3 which is called: http://www.pdelfino.com.br/

After a while, I decided to use the CodePipeline service so that after doing some changes on a git local repository and pushing it to GitHub, the website would be automatically updated. This has worked so far! I did all this by following tutorials (not really understanding what was happening).

Now, I want to add an SSL certificate to have the *https*. Thus, I am following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/wHWOVa5zsIw?t=508) on Youtube and, at some point, the guy suggests choosing the bucket to change it. The problem is that my dashboard lists two buckets, as shown by the image below:

[image]

The fact that two buckets are shown while having one application intrigues. I was expecting to see just one bucket.

1 - Is this due to the CodePipeLine integration? If no, why does it happen?

2 - Is one of these buckets removable?

3 - In order to provide the SSL certificate, which one should I choose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both buckets. For Code Pipeline you need a S3 bucket where the artifacts are sent for deployment (that is the first bucket on your screen shot). The second bucket in your screen shot looks like the bucekt that holds your web site. You do not want to have just one S3 bucket because you will end up with your deployment file from Code Pipeline in your public web site bucket. Choose the second bucket that have the same name as your domain name for your SSL certificate.